# Making custom URLs in Umbraco 7.6 without document type

Tags: c#, url, umbraco, umbraco7, custom-url

### What I have

I'm making a site using Umbraco 7.6.6 and I want to access a third party database of my client. For that I've made a custom controller named `QuestionsController`. Inside this I've created an action:

```csharp
public class QuestionsController : SurfaceController
{
    private QuestionService _questionService = new QuestionService();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/MacroPartials/Questions.cshtml", _questionService.ReadFile());
    }
}
```

This page index page works fine and is called by this code on the view of my document type:

```csharp
Html.RenderAction("index", "Questions");
```

Overview page *(just an image)*:

[image]

Here is my model I've created

```csharp
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

### What I will

Now I'll to create a details page with more information on the front side.

```csharp
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/questions/details/{id}")]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View(_questionService.ReadFile().ElementAt(id));
}
```

Redirecting to that page I'll do like this:

```html
<a href="~/questions/details/@q.ID">@q.Title</a>
```

But this doesn't work at all. The detail page gives me a 404 *(page not found)* error.

### Question

My question is now: How could I create custom URLs like `~/questions/details/{id}` without a document type? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide:

#### Step 1: Add controller

Make your controller and extends from `Controller` instead of `SurfaceController` and return a `JsonResult` instead of a `ActionResult`:

```csharp
public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
    private QuestionService _questionService = new QuestionService();

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return Json(_questionService.ReadFile());
    }
}
```

#### Step 2: add reserved path

Add the controller path to `umbracoReservedPaths` `appSettings` key in your `web.config` file. Any path added to this list will be ignored by Umbraco’s routing engine.

```xml
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/questions/" />
```

#### Step 3: Change or add `global.asax.cs`

Change or add your `global.asax.cs` to inherit from `UmbracoApplication`. Open up your `global.asax.cs` file and change this line:

```csharp
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

to this:

```csharp
public class MvcApplication : UmbracoApplication
```

#### Step 4: Change `global.asax`

Change your `global.asax` to inherit from your application. This was the big gotcha that caught me out and I had to do quite a bit of searching to find it! Open up your `Global.asax` file (right click on it and <kbd>View Markup</kbd>) and change this line:

```asax
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

to this:

```asax
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyProject.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

where `MyProject` in this example is the base namespace of your project.

#### Step 5: Remove default `RouteConfig.cs`

Remove the default custom route from `RouteConfig.cs` if exists. If you don’t remove this route, MVC will try and route every request and your website will show en empty page which may be a nice clean design, but not very functional!

#### Step 6: Register custom routes

Register your custom route in the `RegisterRoutes` method of your `RouteConfig.cs`. If this file doesn't exist, create one under the folder `App_Start`. You have to do this for each route you want use:

```csharp
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { 
    controller = "Questions", 
    action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional 
});
```

#### Step 7: add `OnApplicationStarted`

Finally you need to add an `OnApplicationStarted` override method to `global.asax.cs`. This will allow you to add your application to read the `RegisterRoutes` method in your `RouteConfig.cs` file when it starts, and add the custom route you just set up into your application:

```csharp
protected override void OnApplicationStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnApplicationStarted(sender, e);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

#### Step 8: Code clean up

1. When this steps are done remove next line and the file. This you didn't need anymore.

   ```csharp
   Html.RenderAction("index", "Questions");
   ```
2. Create views for each action. You could do this like the classic MVC applications.

<sup>Source: [maffrigby.com (using custom routes in umbraco)](http://maffrigby.com/using-custom-routes-in-umbraco/)</sup>